# Animating a Circle when pressing UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, cabasicanimation

I am trying to achieve a animation on a `collectionViewCell` after i am pressing it. I have this `CABasicAnimation` call:

```
CGRect frame = self.sharingAnimationView.bounds;

//// Subframes
CGRect group = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + floor(CGRectGetWidth(frame) * 0.02041 + 0.5), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + floor(CGRectGetHeight(frame) * 0.02041 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetWidth(frame) * 0.97959 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetWidth(frame) * 0.02041 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetHeight(frame) * 0.97959 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetHeight(frame) * 0.02041 + 0.5));

//// Oval Drawing
CGRect ovalRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(group) + floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), CGRectGetMinY(group) + floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 1.00000 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetWidth(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5), floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 1.00000 + 0.5) - floor(CGRectGetHeight(group) * 0.00000 + 0.5));
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[ovalPath addArcWithCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(ovalRect), CGRectGetMidY(ovalRect)) radius: CGRectGetWidth(ovalRect) / 2 startAngle: -90 * M_PI/180 endAngle: 270 * M_PI/180 clockwise: YES];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame = self.sharingAnimationView.bounds;
pathLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.lineWidth = 1.5;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
[self.sharingAnimationView.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
[pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
```

This basically create a circle in `sharingAnimationView` and colors it in black. I am calling this method from the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, but it seems like the animation is not happening.

The weird thing is the if i move the animation call to `awakeFromNib` the animation executes great.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's well known behaviour when you first run some UI changes (like standard UIActivityIndicator or custom animation) and next some heavy task. In this case RunLoop doesn't execute UI changes because it expects previous UI cycle to be finished. If you run your business logic in UI thread than your activity indicator doesn't have a chance to be processed at all. Try to first launch your animation inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath and the rest of method put in separate method and call it with minimal delay right after running animation

```
[self performSelector:@selector(mySeparateMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: the animation coed is located in a custom UICollectionViewCell. In  didSelectItemAtIndexPath i'm telling the cell to start the animation